# How to apply two conditions in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to distribute a known number evenly 1 by 1 across a range where the known number is given by "TV Comodin" Row (in color Red), the data set is as follow:

| TV Comodín | L | M | SEGMENTO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Second | 20 | 30 | CD |
| First | 10 | 30 | AB |
| Second | 80 | 30 | AB |
| TV Comodín | 500 | 500 | COMODIN |

The cell has a limit depending on its category given by the column I, "SEGMENTO".
AB category must to be <= 100 and CD category must to be <= 120.

```vb
Sub prueba()
    
    Dim f As Range, ws As Worksheet, comodin As Long, rng As Range, m
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set rng = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 1)
    
    Set f = ws.Columns("A").Find(What:="TV Comodín", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
                                 
    lastRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = i + 1 To lastRow
        If Range("I" & i) = "AB" Then
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                rng.Value = ws.Evaluate("=" & rng.Address() & "*1") 'fill empty cells with zeros
                comodin = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Do While comodin > 0
                    mn = Application.Min(rng)
                    If mn >= 100 Then Exit Do    ' exit when no values are <100
                    m = Application.Match(mn, rng, 0)
                    rng.Cells(m).Value = rng.Cells(m).Value + 1
                    comodin = comodin - 1
                    f.Offset(0, 1).Value = comodin
                Loop
            Else
                MsgBox "No found"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It works with the first condition (AB <= 100).

I tried to add the other condition (CD <= 120) by using Elseif inside the loop.

Desired output

| TV Comodín | L | M | SEGMENTO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Second | 120 | 30 | CD |
| First | 100 | 30 | AB |
| Second | 100 | 30 | AB |
| TV Comodín | 200 | 500 | COMODIN |

Comment: I suggest you set breakpoints (F9) and single step (F8) through the code. That's far better than relying on somebody else to do that for you.

Comment: Without going through your code line by line I am not following what you are trying to achieve. Can you make it a little more explicit what the desired outcome is and how you are arriving at it?

Comment: sure @QHarr , see my question, I've already edited it and added a picture of the desired output

Comment: Be careful highlighting doesn't obscure numbers and it is better to also supply the data as a formatted table which is possible via edit - then people can copy paste. See meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/… I typically use [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) as I can paste data from Excel into it and it generates my markdown table, copy paste that into question, highlight the whole table just pasted and press Ctrl + K to indent properly

Comment: You need to change your col I to col D for the revised dataset.

Comment: I was having a play and I get 100,100,100 as output if I run [something similar](https://pastebin.com/03AGMxs8) to Tim Williams' answer. Are you sure about your output values or has logic changed since your earlier question?

Comment: Yes it does! if you look carefully that post, this code changes a little bit , and how I said on there, i'm a little bit new on VBA and i'm triying to adapt this part in all my solution that has around 700 lines, but thanks I'll keep checking the code to see what is wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.  Basically because you have multiple rules for max value, you need to exclude cells which have already met their maximum value while you process the remaining cells.

When you're done you can "unexclude" the cells.

```vb
Sub prueba()
   
    Dim f As Range, ws As Worksheet, comodin As Long, rng As Range, m, mn
    Dim numExcluded As Long, c As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set rng = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 1)
    
    Set f = ws.Columns("A").Find(What:="TV Comodín", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
                                 
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        
        rng.Value = ws.Evaluate("=" & rng.Address() & "*1") 'fill empty cells with zeros
        comodin = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
        'Loop while we still have additions to make and
        '  all cells have not been excluded
        Do While comodin > 0 And numExcluded < rng.Count
            mn = Application.Min(rng)
            m = Application.Match(mn, rng, 0)
            Set c = rng.Cells(m) 'get the matched cell
            
            If mn < GetMax(c.Offset(0, 2)) Then 'my SEGMENTO are in ColD
                c.Value = c.Value + 1
                comodin = comodin - 1
            Else
                'This cell already at max value: exclude for now...
                c.Value = "x" & c.Value
                numExcluded = numExcluded + 1
            End If
        Loop
        f.Offset(0, 1).Value = comodin
        
        ' "unexclude" any excluded cells
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If c.Value Like "x*" Then c.Value = Right(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 1)
        Next c
    Else
        MsgBox "No found"
    End If
End Sub

Function GetMax(v)
    Select Case v
        Case "AB": GetMax = 100
        Case "CD": GetMax = 120
        Case Else: GetMax = 200
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for your kindness, it works perfectly and also I understand your logic. Just a quick question i'm trying that the values in the function can be variables, this variables would be enter with InputBox for the user. So i'm using ByVal but it just works for one variable do you have and idea how to add ByVal on there? when I use something like this GetMax(ByVal myValue1 As Integer, ByVal myValue2 As Integer) don't work either

Comment: Sorry I'm not following you.  GetMax converts a string "Ab" or "CD" to a number, so it's not clear what you mean by `GetMax(ByVal myValue1 As Integer, ByVal myValue2 As Integer)`  Do you mean the user assigns a maximum value for "Ab" and "CD"?

Comment: yes! just like that, user assigns a maximum value for "AB" and "CD". I'm trying to add that in your solution, sorry for my bad explanation. Do you have any idea to get that?

Comment: You can use InputBox to get two numbers from the user, one for AB and the other for CD, and use those numbers in place of the GetMax function.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I made that, and put those variables as public variables to have that flexibility, it works so well. Thanks for your time.